# How to do lap times using PHP code?

Tags: php

there are time start n time end in every task. lap times will restart a new time to the next task. after all task has been done. the duration of each lap times will be taken and recorded to the database. this is what i wanted to do but i really don't know how since i'm new in PHP. help me! Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried any thing? Just show your code and tell us what is your difficulties. We will help. SO is not a place to do your homework.

Comment: i'm a beginner . and i haven't tried anything since i don't know the code. i am currently developing the system in my final year project and this problem is one of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$newlapstart = microtime();
.... // do something here
$newlapend = microtime();
$lap_time = ($newlapend-$newlapstart); //micro-seconds
```

Comment: do we need to create a new db for lap time?

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
$laptimes = array();
```

after comleting a task:

```
$laptimes[] = $timeend - $timestart;
```

when all is done;

```
foreach($laptimes as $laptime) {
$db = new Mysqli();
$query = "INSERT INTO tablename VALUES ('$laptime');";
$db->query ($query);
}
```

Comment: $laptimes[] = $timeend - $timestart; 
this code used to calculate duration, isnt?

Comment: Actually it does two things. Calculate the duration, and keep it in an array for later processing.

$duration = $timeend - $timestart;
$laptimes[] = $duration;

Comment: Please use a prepared statement. `$laptime` might be a computed (safe) value but your answer **promotes using unsafe SQL**. People who learn using SO will adopt these practices giving birth to the next generation of SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks Bart for your suggestions